# How can I set a certain cck value to selected nodes using View Bulk Operation (VBO)?

Tags: 6, entities, views

I have a text type cck filed (checkbox widget) allowing multiple values.
I need to add one of the values of this field to selected nodes using VBO.
I suppose `Modify node fields (views_bulk_operations_fields_action)` is the way to go but how can I exactly do it?
I need to add just one value but keeping the existing values the nodes currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view, and add Bulk Operation to the field.
In the configuration field: Bulk Operations: Content
  Bulk Operations -> Selected Operations,  you can choose the operations you would like to perform in bulk. 
  Once you done, save the view, and go to the view page.

1. Select the nodes you would like to edit
2. Choose an operation, click `Execute`
3. Select the field you like to edit
4. You got the rest.

Comment: Thanks.Is there way to do it without overriding the existing values? I also edited the description.

Comment: aw, I see. So you wanna select additional values to selected nodes. Sry, I'm still kinda new. I didn't find an option in the settings that meets your need.

Comment: I guess you can try directly manipulate the database if you wanna just add one more value to all the nodes.

Comment: They said it's supposed to provide an option that allows you to prevent the override, but I don't see it anywhere. Here's the [link](http://drupal.org/node/1105494)